# HTML Table - Column Width Auto Adjust

Tags: html, mysql, css

I have a table that gives output such as illustrated in the image here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B48p5hM0mJhVUVFmSm1Sem9jMHc/view?usp=sharing

The number of columns are different against each entry and there is no fixed number of columns. The number of columns changes with each query.

How can I make the width of all columns fit the space ? 
Ideally, I would like the column span to expand to fill the area evenly, like in the heading. Alternately, I could also do with empty / blank columns where the number of columns is less than the maximum.

Here is my code:

```
<table width="auto" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<th bgcolor="#0080FF"><div align="left"><font color="#000000" face="Arial,    Helvetica, sans-serif">Equipment </font></div></th>
<th bgcolor="#0080FF" colspan="100%"><div align="center"><font    color="#000000" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Problems Reported </font>        </div></th>
</tr>

<?php
$t=0;
while ($t < $nume) 
{
$e1=mysql_result($resulte,$t,"EQUIP");
?>

<tr>
<td bgcolor="#D7D7FF"><div align="left"><strong><font color="#000000" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php if(empty($e1)) {echo 'Unlisted Equipment';} else {echo $e1;} ?></font></strong></div></td>

<?php
$queryX = "SELECT NATR, COUNT(NATR) AS COUNT FROM (
(SELECT NATR FROM main WHERE EQUIP = '$e1' AND DATE >='$x2' AND DATE <= '$x5')
UNION ALL (SELECT NATR2 AS NATR FROM main WHERE EQUIP = '$e1' AND DATE >='$x2' AND DATE <= '$x5' AND NATR2 <> '')
UNION ALL (SELECT NATR3 AS NATR FROM main WHERE EQUIP = '$e1' AND DATE>='$x2' AND DATE <= '$x5' AND NATR3 <> '')
) t GROUP BY NATR";
$resultX = mysql_query($queryX);
$rowX = mysql_fetch_array($resultX);
$numX=mysql_numrows($resultX);

$w=0; 
while ($w < $numX) 
{
$w1=mysql_result($resultX,$w,"NATR");
$w2=mysql_result($resultX,$w,"COUNT");
?>
<td bgcolor="#D7D7FF"><div align="left"><font color="#000000" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $w1; ?></font></div></td>
<td bgcolor="#D7D7FF"><div align="center"><font color="#000000" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $w2; ?></font></div></td>



<?php
$w++;
}
?>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out a simple work around. Since I know the number of rows; that eventually end up as columns in the table. I multiplied $numX by 2 (to find out number of columns required for my specific query) **$numX=mysql_numrows($resultX)** --> **$NO = $numX * 2**

After that I simply divided that number in colspan by 100: **td colspan= < ? php echo 100/$NO; ? >**

It is working very well for me. Thanks for the help guys.

```
$queryX = "SELECT NATR, COUNT(NATR) AS COUNT FROM (blah blah blah) t GROUP BY NATR";
$resultX = mysql_query($queryX);
$rowX = mysql_fetch_array($resultX);
$numX=mysql_numrows($resultX);
$NO = $numX * 2;

<?php
$w=0; 
while ($w < $numX) 
{
$w1=mysql_result($resultX,$w,"NATR");
$w2=mysql_result($resultX,$w,"COUNT");
?>

<td colspan="<?php echo 100/$NO; ?>"><div align="left"><?php echo $w1; ?></div></td>
<td colspan="<?php echo 100/$NO; ?>"><div align="center"><?php echo $w2; ?></div></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the variable column numbers with variable width.
You can apply the width dynamically. The total page width is 100%.
So give the width of column in % value.
Suppose you have 5 columns then the width calculate like 100 / 5 = 20%.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: That is a good suggestion but I am not sure weather the columns will be 5 or 6 or 8 ... If we can count the number of columns generated and use a formula to calculate the percentage, then it could do; unless there is a simpler way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
table { 
  width: 100%; 
  border-collapse: collapse; 
}

tr:nth-of-type(odd) { 
  background: #eee; 
}
th { 
  background-color: #0080FF; 
  color: #000000; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 6px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  text-align: left; 
}
td { 
  padding: 6px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  text-align: left; 
  background: #D7D7FF; 
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-weight: bold; 
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<th><div align="left">Equipment</div></th>
<th><div align="left">Problems Reported </div></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div align="left">sample</div></td>
<td><div align="left">sample</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank You for your response. I tried using this code, the output is still the same with uneven columns. It only changed the style slightly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jquery script that will loop on all rows to determine maximum column count, then divide it to 100% and set the quotient % as column width.

With your sample code you need to fix/change your approach on fetching **$queryX** so you could insert **<td>&nbsp;</td>** to fill in floating td.

```
var columnCountArray = [],
    maxColumnCount = 0,
    columnWidthPercent = 100;

$.each($("table tr"), function(e){
    columnCountArray.push($(this).find("td").length);
})

maxColumnCount = Math.max.apply(Math, columnCountArray);
columnWidthPercent = 100 / maxColumnCount;
$(".problems").attr("width",  columnWidthPercent + "%");
```